# Laravel Eloquent - querying Transactions on the bases of months

Tags: sql, laravel, eloquent

I have a transaction table in which I have a date on which a transaction occurred. Date is stored as "04-24-2021" as "m-d-Y" format. I want to get transactions occurring in every month from the latest to oldest transaction. For example, if the latest transaction occurred in '04-24-2021' and the oldest occurred in '02-04-2020' then I want to get transactions grouped by months from 04-2021 to  04-2020. What is the best way to do so?

Comment: Can you provide,What you have tried yet

Comment: I tried to make an array and manually put year and month in that but i have to query for all months if i do this.

  $transactions = Transaction::whereMonth( 'date', $latestMonth )->whereYear( 'date', $latestYear )->get();

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
DB::table('transactions')
    ->select('transactions.*', DB::raw('DATE_FORMAT(transactions.date, "%m-%Y") month_year')
    ->get()
    ->groupBy('month_year');
```

General idea: we format the `transactions.date` into month_date then use SQL `groupBy`